# TableView Cell open different view

Tags: ios

I have tableview with 3 rows and I have 3 view (xib). I want to click on Row 1 it opens View1, click Row 2 it opens View2...

I am new in iOS.
Please help, thank in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you see the code in the template from Apple in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
@class YourClass : ParentClass <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    yourTableView.delegate = self;
    yourTableView.dataSource = self
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
     switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1:
        {
          //open view 1
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
          //open view 2
        }
            break;
        case 3:
        {
         //open view 3   
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```